# Refresh browser using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sh, wget

The goal is to create a bash script to refresh a webpage every five seconds and I've been struggling to do it. I know crontab would probably work butI'd rather just do it as a bash script...
So I have this code right here:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This script will reload/refresh a webpage every 5 seconds"

while true;
do

wget http://website.com/ >/dev/null
sleep 2;

done
```

and it works for the most part. It downloads the webpage but doesn't refresh it like I want it to. I've tried adding an '-e' after 'wget' but it says its an invalid command. I've also used 'curl' instead of 'wget' and I like how 'curl' shows feedback rather than also downloading but again, it doesn't refresh the page...

I've also tried something along the lines of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
do
iceweasel -remote "openURL(website.com)"
sleep 10;

done
```

It does its job and opens the webpage I want, but it keeps adding tab after tab every 10 seconds. I tried to use the killall command to close the tab before it goes through the loop again, that way it would be something similar what I'm going for but it doesn't work either.
It's probably something very simple but I just really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You already a great solution [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42933/25919)

Comment: Wrong tool for the job. This is something it makes **vastly** more sense to do in JavaScript code running inside the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having a script that presses F5 or ctrl+r automatically for you at a gui web browser, then you can do what sjsam suggested and use xdotool.

(Make sure you install xdotool)

```
while true ; do
    sleep 2
    xdotool key ctrl+r
done
```

Comment: @TuxForLife If I have many tabs open how can I find the specific URL and only refresh that page?